# Django filter related data

Tags: django

I need to make a queryset on django and I want to filter both a model and its related model. Like I need to get all PartRequest's that are created by a seller and I want to retrieve only his bid attatched.

```
class PartRequest(models.Model):

class Bid(models.Model):

    seller      = models.ForeignKey(UserSeller, related_name='seller_bid')
    request     = models.ForeignKey(PartRequest, related_name='request_bid')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this is what you want

```
bids = Bid.objects.filter(seller=your seller here)
partRequests = bids.values_list('request', flat=True)
```

Comment: i am using something like that... but i wanted everything inside the same object

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it as an instance of a particular model if you want it as a single object. Take a look at `raw()` for what you want.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/